Inserting data to kafka topic with Flink SQL using the kubernetes operator
I am trying to run the following code:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_source_table
(
    myField1     VARCHAR,
    myField2      VARCHAR
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'demo',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '***',
    'properties.group.id' = 'some-id-1',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
    'format' = 'json',
    'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
    'scan.topic-partition-discovery.interval'= '60000',
    'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
    'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true',
    'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_SSL',
    'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'PLAIN',
    'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=*** password=***;',
    'properties.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' = 'https'
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_sink_table
(
    myField1     VARCHAR,
    myField2      VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (`myField1`) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
    'topic' = 'demosink',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '***',
    'key.format' = 'json',
    'value.format' = 'json',
    'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_SSL',
    'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'PLAIN',
    'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=*** password=***;',
    'properties.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' = 'https'
);

INSERT INTO some_sink_table SELECT * FROM some_source_table;

I can see that I am consuming data in the Confluent platform, but no data is produced to the demosink topic.
I have tried to add dependencies to the example given here.
I have tried to add the following dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-sql-connector-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

I use Flink version 1.19.1. Am I missing some dependency or are some of my dependencies incompatible? I have also tried to copy the flink-sql-connector-kafka and
flink-clients .jar file into the lib folder inside the dockerfile.

Do you have any error messages ? Because normally you can't read standard kafka topic ('connector' = 'kafka') and insert directly to 'upsert-kafka'. 'upsert-kafka' tables require to define a PRIMARY KEY constraint.

I get Error connecting to node b5-{BOOTSTRAP_SERVER} (id: 5 rack: 2) java.net.UnknownHostException: b5-{BOOTSTRAP_SERVER}: Name or service not known. I get this error message with b0-, b1-, b2- and b5-. I have the PRIMARY KEY ('myField1') NOT ENFORCED in upsert-kafka is this not how you add a PRIMARY KEY? @Niko

I dont know the real problem with your bootstrap server. Try to add error log to your post. Flink probably can't access to servers because your kafka container not sharing the same network with Flink. You have PRIMARY KEY in your sink table but your source table doesn't have it. Read this doc for better understanding

The problem was with properties.sasl.jaas.config. Duplicate of this
